# Формат файла для хранения информации с последующим поиском по ней

Tags: база-данных, firebird, алгоритм, visual-c++

Доброго времени суток, Хэшкодовцы!

Не знаю как правильно кратко описать проблему в заголовке, так что придется описать все подробно.

Есть программа, которая должна отображать информацию в удобном виде. Информация содержит следующую информацию:

- Форматированный текст;
- Картинки;
- Таблицы с информацией;
- Ссылки на веб ресуры;
- Ссылки на E-mail;
- Ссылки на места в этом же документе;
- Ссылки на файлы в другом документе, но относящиеся к одному хранилищу (группа документов объединенных одной тематикой по смыслу или требованиями руководством);
- Документы в одной группе (объединенные документы) должны быть привязаны к веткам дерева, т.е. быть структурированы.

Программа просмотра этих документов должна уметь:

- Производить поиск в одном документе по тексту;
- Производить поиск в нескольких документах по тексту;
- Отображать документы в режиме только чтения (редактирование не требуется), сохраняя оформления;
- Корректно обрабатывать ссылки перехода внутри документа;
- В идеале уметь работать с тэгами, составляя список индексов и переходить по ним на конкретный документ в определенное место документа;

Собственно, что пробовалось сделать:

- Все красиво, все как нужно было сделано при помощи chm формата, но так как просмоторщик их дурной (hh.exe), да и является сторонним приложением, то это не сильно подходит. + ко всему нет возможности управлять системой поиска. Блокирование печати и копирования документа реализовано через hook, что является крайне не красивым решением, да и антивирусы на это смотрят криво, некоторые вообще блокируют данный фунционал блокировки.
- Пробовали документы перегонять в RTF формат, но они очень сильно пухнут от картинок (т.к. картинка в них преставляет не что иное, как кодированное бинарное хранилище в текстовом виде, из-за чего 1 байт информации становится несколькими байтами. + ко всему, для возможности объединения этих RTF в одну группу, и работу в виде дерева с ними, они были сохранены в blob поля базы firebird и полнотекстовый поиск в них стал не возможен (до firebird 3.0, полнотекстовый поиск не реализован). Следовательно требуется их вытаскивать, что занимает много времени. Более того, rtf просмоторщик в VC++ жутко глючный и отображение сложных таблиц и форматированного текста вечно куда-то уплывает. RichTextView есть и по новее, но он входит в состав MS Office, на что завязывать тоже нельзя, т.к. является сторонней разработкой. Для поиск по всему тексту было реализовано индексирование документов, что базу данных еще увеличило в два раза. ИТОГО этот вариант практически все позволяет, но он сложен в наполнении (тяжело создать такой формат документа), он жутко долго производит поиск, глючит в отображении сложного текста, он увеличивает размер файла практически в 4-5 раз по сравнению с chm форматом.

В общем ищу варианты как разработать просмоторщик документов, какой формат использовать. В идеале какой-нибудь не сложный формат.
Одно из важных требований - файл итоговый должен получиться один (или несколько, но не должно зависеть от количество документов внутри). CHM всем хорош, кроме того, что он вымирает, и для его просмотра требуется стороннее приложение.

PS: Еще рассматривался вариант документы хранить в html, но такой документ придется потрошить и как-то запихивать в БД, а потом также все эти куски как-то в памяти разворачивать соединять и подсовывать html просмоторщику (видел исходники всяких там chrome, фаерфоксов, которые позволяют сделать свой контрол для просмотра).

PPS: Может быть у кого-нибудь есть другие идеи по реализации и по формату базы для документов?

Спасибо, что дочитали до конца.

Comment: Вы удивитесь, но встроенного просмотрщика rtf в Visual C++ вовсе нету.

Comment: @vladd, не удивлюсь =) знаю, что используется от ms просмоторщик. Только в винде он старый, который глючный до ужаса. Есть новая версия, но она идет только в поставке MSOffice свежих версий. Его также можно выцепить путем поставки нескольких ДЛЛ, только это нарушения лицензионного соглашения. Отдельно я этого просмоторщика от MS не встречал :-(

Comment: @pincher1519: Если использовать WPF, [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx) очень хорошо справляется с RTF. Для WinForms `RichTextBox` также обладает свойством [`Rtf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf.aspx).

Comment: @vladd, к сожалению, фрэймворк использовать нельзя. Кстати у этого текст бокса проблемы со сложными таблицами также наблюдаются, например с таблицами, в которых есть объединения ячеек по горизонтали и вертикали. Да и проблему большого объёма документа не решает, собственно как и полно текстового поиска.

Comment: @vladd, Сейчас рассматриваю ситуацию с сохранением html в базу данных, добавление в текст своих ссылок, потрошение документа на картинки и текст, помещение этого всего в блоб поля, текст может еще зипом запакуем, для ещё большего ужатия, хотя посмотрим по скорости работы. Для полно текстового поиска сделаем индексацию по словам с привязкой к документам и положению слова в тексте... Правда эта индексация практически в два раза увеличивает базу данных. А если не индексировать, то для полного поиска придётся последовательно вытаскивать документы и искать в них, что займёт гораздо больше времени.

Answer (score 1):

docx  -  там внутри xml

Comment: Не решает проблемы полно текстового поиска, нечем просматривать, придётся тащить сторонний просмоторщик. Да, согласен, что защита от редактирования есть, но защитить от копирования информации и печати, на сколько могу предполагать - нет. Навязывать конечному пользователю ms word viewer с дополнительным модулем просмотра docx формата не есть правильно. Pdf формат по тем же соображениям отсеивался - нечем смотреть его.